# How to persist User data and link to a TouchID React-native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-redux, react-native-ios

I'm building an iOS app using React-native with Expo.  I have TouchID working just fine, my issue is after recognizing a successful fingerprint at the login screen how can I access the user, specifically the username and email associated with this Fingerprint?

Obviously, I need to persist this data somewhere as there will only be one user's Fingerprints per device, but I need some specifics on what the best practices for doing this with the said technologies. (iOS, Expo, React-native, Redux)

Comment: I'm also facing a similar problem. we have LocalAuthentication and SecureStore in Expo. But there is nothing connecting between these two. Like requiring LocalAuthentication success response before SecureStore is read. SecureStore can be read and written without any extra authentication. Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Assuming you are using the expo-local-authentication library and firebase auth. Not sure its the correct way but what I did was once a user logs in they can toggle on to use the finger print. When they do this I grab the users refresh token and store it in my locale secure storage using the expo-secure-store library which encrypts what you store locally on the device. Than when the user uses the fingerprint I check the secure local storage for their refresh token and use that to sign them in. So maybe something similar would work for you.